# Right and Bottom CSS property not working

Tags: css, properties

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Review of animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css">
</head>
<body >
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code:

```
div{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:darkorange;
    animation-name: rotation;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    position:absolute;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

}

@keyframes rotation {
    0%{
        background-color: darkorange;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        
    }
    25%{
        background-color: darksalmon;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        
    }
    50%{
        background-color:deepskyblue;
        right: 0px;
        bottom:0px;
        
    }
    75%{
        background-color: lightblue;
        bottom:0px;
        left:0px;
    }
    100%{
        background-color: darkorange;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
    }
    
}
```

I'm trying to get the box animating each corner of the browser screen but due to right and bottom properties malfunction the animation is stuck in the corner. The workaround
instead of right=0 using left=100% is working, but my question is why right=0 not working?

Comment: I was stuck on this for five hours. Couldn't figure out why bottom and right didn't work. I gave up and did the workaround XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to travel you have to use just top and left and give them values in `px` as following code:
Edit: It's better to use css `transforms` for animations cause they are hardware accelarated and have a smoother transition.

```css
#object {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#object2 {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  animation-name: accelarated;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@keyframes animation {
  0% {left: 0; top:0;}
  25% {left: 100px; top:0;}
  50% {left: 100px; top:100px;}
  75% {left: 0; top:100px;}
  100% {left: 0; top:0;}
}

@keyframes accelarated {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(100px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(100px, 100px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(0, 100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="object"></div>
<div id="object2"></div>
```

Comment: You just perfected the solution. But again why right and bottom can not make travel?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to set a position you also have to reset the other two position to initial value which is `auto`. Also when value is 0 there's no need to use `px`.

```css
div{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:darkorange;
    animation-name: rotation;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    position:absolute;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

}

@keyframes rotation {
    0%{
        background-color: darkorange;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        
    }
    25%{
        background-color: darksalmon;
        top:0;
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        bottom: auto;
        
    }
    50%{
        background-color:deepskyblue;
        top:auto;
        left:auto;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        
    }
    75%{
        background-color: lightblue;
        top:auto;
        left:0;
        right: auto;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    100%{
        background-color: darkorange;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right: auto;
        bottom: auto;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @amirify for solving the problem. But how auto determine the value?

Comment: Auto Lets the browser calculate position from the edge. This is default. The positions that have a value rather than `auto` determine the position of element.

Comment: Thanks again @amirify one problem: I want the box to travel around the corner, not popping out on each corner.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set already left = 0, and width 50px, unless you set left value to unset, right = 0 won't work.
they can't be compatible.
left =0 & right = 0 then, width must be 100%, but with has sticky value for 50px;

So, you can do like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>


.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red
}
.child{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:darkorange;
    animation-name: rotation;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    position:absolute;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    0%{
        background-color: darkorange;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }
    25%{
        background-color: darksalmon;
        top: 0px;
        left: calc(100% - 50px)
    }
    50%{
        background-color:deepskyblue;
        top: calc(100% - 50px);
        left: calc(100% - 50px)
    }
    75%{
        background-color: lightblue;
        top: calc(100% - 50px);
        left: 0px;
    }
    100%{
        background-color: darkorange;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }
}
```